# Google maps API rendering not everytime. Using navigator geolocation

Tags: google-maps, asynchronous, dictionary, geolocation, render

I have a very particular problem, I'm using Google maps API to render a map on a web application, the map takes up the whole of the screen and that's as far as I want to go for the moment. The issue is that it renders on the Web Application most of the time, but some times it just presents the "zoom bar" and the buttons for "satellite view" and "map view" if I refresh the page, it would (maybe) render normally.

This is my JS

```
/*Define my latitude and longitud globals*/
var latitude;
var longitude;

/*
 * Wait until everything (dependencies) has been loaded to the page
 * running start to get the ball rolling
 */
$(document).ready(function() { start(); });

/*Bootstrap funct*/
function start() {
deviceLocation();
setMapSize();
loadScript();
}

function deviceLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(ok) {
        latitude = ok.coords.latitude;
        longitude = ok.coords.longitude;
 }, function(error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        latitude = 40.013857;
        longitude = -101.685508;
  });
}
/* If geolocation not supported then we default to these coordinates */
else {
    latitude = 40.013857;
    longitude = -101.685508;
}
}

function setMapSize() {
windowHeight = $(window).height();
headerHeight = $('#header').height();
$('.indexMainContainer').css('height', (windowHeight - headerHeight));
}

function loadScript() {
 var script = document.createElement('script');
 script.type = 'text/javascript';
 script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&' +
  'callback=initialize&key=AIzaSyB2M8upR6PVkuKckRYl4C_gQp2D9sHQTD8';
 document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function initialize() {
 var mapOptions = {
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude),
 zoom: 15    
};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  mapOptions);
}
```

And well, the html is :

```
<div id="map">
</div>
```

I have some suspicions regarding asynchronously coordinates-fetching using geolocator, (maybe it's taking too long to provide coordinates), but I wouldn't know how to make it work if that's the issue.

Thanks in advanced for any help.

Comment: Asynchronous nature of `geocode()` is most probably root cause of this problem. You can call `loadScript()` only in case if lat/lng are defined and wait if not. Or define latitude and longitude with values from the beginning (40.013857, -101.685508).

Comment: I figured, I will try to cook a better script to manage this issue. Thanks for your input.